# Adjustable macro delay (by entering time in cell)

Tags: vba, excel, delay, adjustable

**Anwser: Change Cell format from D3 into Text instead of General or Time**

I'm trying to delay a macro by a variable amount of time.

And I'd like to be able to adjust the amount of delay in my excel workbook without having to open a macro.

I tryed the code below but got :

> run time error 13 (Type mismatch).

Is this solvable?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim Response As Integer
    t = Range("D3")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("t"))
```

-Cell Format: First Tryed Time (0:00:00), then changed it back to general.

-The data in Cell "D3" : 0:00:00, 0:00:01, 0:30:00 or higher values.

- Error occures @ Application.Wait....ect line

-Time format= General --> t turns out to be something like 0,00000453*E-5 When "D3" is 0:00:01

Time format = time --> t turns out to be empty (using the 37:23:23 time format)

Comment: Can you specify, the data you input in "D3" and the format of that cell? Also on which line do you get the error! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In facts, it is pretty simple mistake, **Just change`TimeValue("t")` to `TimeValue(t)`**

---

**Why is that?**

You need to input a time value formatted as text into `TimeValue()` function, you are getting this value properly into the variable `t`.

The problem is when you reuse this, because `"t"` is a String only containing the `t` letter and not the variable `t`!

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim Response As Integer
    t = CStr(Range("D3"))
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue(t))
```

Comment: Thanks for the very clear explaination, but unfortunatly I'm still getting te same error.

- Changed ("t") into (t)
-Changed the cell's  Category back into General instead of time

-Tryed to enter 0:00:01 instead of 0:00:00

But both changes didn't make any sence.

(thanks for your anwser, although it didn't work it was at least explained very clear. "give a man a fish and he'll have food for a day, learn a man how to fish and he will never be hungry again")

Comment: Set the **format of the cell D3 to Text** and take a look at the edited code, I added `CStr()` function to convert your input as a `String` to avoid any misinterpretation from Excel! ;)

Comment: Changing Cell "D3"into text format was sufficient to fix my problem! Thanks a lot.